# Is it a bad idea to travel to the USA when I have been to China with the same passport?

Tags: usa, passports, tourist-visas, passport-stamps

I am from Germany and plan to travel to the USA later this year. Following the current administration's questionable immigration and travel policies, I have concerns that I might get into trouble when I try to enter the USA because I have been to China a few years back. This is, of course, reflected by the stamp in my passport.

Should I get a new passport just to be safe?

Could this cause problems when applying for a tourist visa?

And is there anything else regarding my passport that I should know when entering the USA (is biometric data necessary?)?

Comment: We welcome people from all over the world. Current immigration policies are temporary. Have a great time in the USA!

Comment: @Mawg well, if they keep it up with this "climate change hoax" they might get on the list nevertheless

Comment: @TG01 I spent seven happy years working in NC and FL and would be happy to come back again - even now. In fact, I am looking to run in next year's Disney marathon, so might look for a job when I am over.   In the meantime, you might want ot bet for or against http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/donald-trump-impeachment-odds-inauguration-halved-bookies-latest-money-president-a7535696.html  :-)  Have a great day

Comment: @Mawg No need to worry, where would all those cheap ties get produced?

Comment: http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/donald-trump-admits-gear-made-china-labels/story?id=13472355  :-)

Comment: Rather than calling US's immigration policies 'questionable'... how about you ask some questions?  There are a very limited suspension of certain countries.  None of these countries are in Asia or Europe (IIRC).  The suspension does not effect people who have happened to travel to these countries.  These countries have been restricted before (of similar nature, different scope).  These countries have unique situations that make vetting difficult - how do you vet someone from Syria for example?

Comment: @NPSF3000 1. Syria, Iran, Iraq and Yemen are all in Western **Asia**. 2. Germany took approximately 1 million refugees which is still dwarved by other countries (Turkey, Pakistan, Iran), the main part exactly from the war-torn Syria and no, the attack in Berlin came from a Tunisian. Osama bin Laden could enter the USA if he were still alive, but the countries which are responsible for exactly 0 dead US citizens (1975-2015) in the USA are blocked. Please explain why it is not "questionable".

Comment: @ThorstenS. Iran is in what is known as the 'middle east'... not to be confused with typically considered Asian countries like Singapore, Indonesia or China.  Germany hasn't been banned.  Please stick to facts, not misdirection.

Comment: @NPSF3000: I'd recommend that you don't confuse what *you* think is a typical Asian country with what people actually know to be Asian countries. As you seem to care about facts: Most Asian countries are neither Singapore, Indonesia, nor China. Oh, and in case you didn't know, here's another fact for you: There is indeed a notable number of German citizens who have been banned from entering the US due to their dual citizenship.

Comment: @Schmuddi "people actually know to be Asian countries."  Iraq == Asian.  China != Asian?  WOW!  

Yes, Iran can be called 'west Asia' but 'west Asia' is a "concept is in limited use, as it significantly overlaps with the Middle East" - either way the argument stands.  China is not in West Asia.

"There is indeed a notable number of German citizens who have been banned from entering the US due to their dual citizenship."

So none of them have been suspended for being German, or for visiting a suspended country?  You mean, like I argue, this has no impact on the OP?

Comment: @NPSF3000 _Rather than calling US's immigration policies 'questionable'... how about you ask some questions?_ The question was right there, didn't you see it ? Anyway, let me save this from your comment before you delete it: `There are a very limited suspension of certain countries. None of these countries are in Asia or Europe (IIRC).` (so no, you don't RC).

Comment: @NPSF3000 Recalling your claim: You claimed none of the banned countries are in Asia (wrong), you inclined the population of the banned countries cannot be trusted because they cannot be vetted (A million of them are in Germany and none comitted a terror act yet so it is unconvincing) and you indicated that is nothing wrong with the ban (despite major *actual* terrorist home countries like Saudi Arabia and VAE which committed 9/11 missing on the list). So who is misdirecting ? And behaving like a jerk to other countries is ok as long as the own country is not involved ?!

Comment: @ThorstenS. " in Asia (wrong)" Correct using the normal definition of Asia.  Pendants using 'western Asia' are using a 'limited use' definition to deflect from that actual point in question.  Rather than address the issue, they'd rather play dumb.  

Same with Germany.  We are not discussing Germany's immigration policies.  

If you consider Saudi and VAE issues due to 9/11 (15 years ago) relevant then you must truly believe that US immigration is incapable of learning to vet anyone at all and should block all immigration.

Comment: It's entertaining to watch some people swinging like that. So @NPSF3000 in which continent those countries are?

Comment: @NPSF3000 Tashfeen Malik, 2015, ex-Pakistani, living most of her life in Saudi Arabia, the Boston Bombers, 2013 from Kyrgyzstan (*Central* Asia, **not** Middle East, still not a "typical Asian country", *surprise*), Faisal Shahzad, 2010, also ex-Pakistani. None would be caught with the travel ban. I do not even blame the immigration because detecting single perpetrators is like trying to sieve the ocean, the current travel ban is only the icing on the cake by using sieves with specific big holes because it filters better (?).

Comment: @SantiBailors Do you argue that Syria (etc) is in a similar geographical area as China?  Y/N?  Even Thorsten has the decency to point out they belong in 'western Asia' a geographical area that does not include China or Germany.

Comment: @ThorstenS.  Why bring up Kyrgyzstan?  As you note, this is not included in the immigration suspension.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You do not need a new passport. China is the third biggest trade partner of the USA next to Canada and the European Union. China is the country which sends the 7th largest number of tourists to the USA. The Chinese even have visa with 10 year validity specifically for Americans. Despite the bombast in political rhetoric, they essentially are joined at the hip economically.

A German tourist with a China visa and stamp in his passport will not face ANY problems (*related to your stated concerns*) when visiting the USA.

Per [Department of Homeland Security](https://www.dhs.gov/e-passports):

> The United States requires that travelers entering the United States
>   under the Visa Waiver Program have an e-Passport if their passport was
>   issued on or after October 26, 2006.

Comment: @ian_itor the US and China even have a relatively recent agreement to grant each other's citizens short-term visitor visas with ten years' validity (2014 it seems). So the US treats Chinese citizens about as favorably as it can without adding China to the VWP. It would be very odd in that context for the US to make problems for citizens of other countries who've visited China.

Comment: With knowledge about those agreements my question seems weird, indeed. I do not travel much outside Europe, so I thought I'd rather ask.

Comment: There is a quick check you can do for many pairs of countries. If there are direct flights from X to Y, the Y immigration authorities are used to dealing with planeloads of people who have all been to X. Any rules about prior travel to X will be clearly stated.

Comment: Almost correct (and +1), but I don't think *"A German tourist with a China visa and stamp in his passport will not face ANY problems when visiting the USA."* is correct. He/she won't face any problems *because of that Visa and stamp*. But he/she might face problems for other reasons, for instance if he/she is a dual citizen of one of the countries on the list. Perhaps you might edit.

Comment: @abligh  https://www.thelocal.de/20170201/problems-for-german-dual-citizens-under-trumps-travel-ban-resolved